# Vectorizing loops in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize a loop iteration using NumPy but am struggling to achieve the desired results. I have an array of pixel values, so 3 dimensions, say (512,512,3) and need to iterate each x,y and calculate another value using a specific index in the third dimension. An example of this code in a standard loop is as follows:

```
for i in xrange(width):
    for j in xrange(height):
        temp = math.sqrt((scalar1-array[j,i,1])**2+(scalar2-array[j,i,2])**2)
```

What I am currently doing is this:

```
temp = np.sqrt((scalar1-array[:,:,1])**2+(scalar2-array[:,:,2])**2)
```

The temp array I get from this is the desired dimensions (x,y) but some of the values differ from the loop implementation. How can I eliminate the loop to compute this example efficiently in NumPy?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here is code that is giving me differing results for temp and temp2, obviously temp2 is just the calculation for one cell

```
temp = np.sqrt((cb_key-fg_cbcr_array[:,:,1])**2+(cr_key-fg_cbcr_array[:,:,2])**2)
temp2 = np.sqrt((cb_key-fg_cbcr_array[500,500,1])**2+(cr_key-fg_cbcr_array[500,500,2])**2)
print temp[500, 500]
print temp2
```

The output for the above is

12.039

94.069123521

The scalars are definitely initialized and the array is generated from an image using

```
fg = PIL.Image.open('fg.jpg')
fg_cbcr = fg.convert("YCbCr")
fg_cbcr_array = np.array(fg_cbcr)
```

Edit2:

Ok so I have tracked it down to a problem with my array. Not sure why yet but it works when the array is generated with np.random.random but not when loading from a file using PIL as above.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me, can you show a full example of your problem. Please make sure that you are not having some kind of machine epsilon problem or printing issue.

Comment: Are the arrays still different if you replace `math.sqrt` by `np.sqrt` in your for loop?

Comment: Yea np.sqrt still gives me desired results within the loop

Comment: Your test case is still returning the exact same results with a trial array created by `np.random.rand`. Please show an example of the difference.

Comment: The values are very different from what I expect so I don't believe it to be an epsilon issue. Is there a way to compare arrays to rule out a printing issue? The implementation stopped working when I swapped to this method and I used prints to track it down to this line producing differing results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vectorized solution is correct.

- in your for loop `temp` is a scalar value that will take only the last value
- use `np.sqrt` istead of `math.sqrt` for vectorized inputs
- you should not use `array` as a variable since it can shadow the `np.array` method

I checked using the following code, which may give you some tip about where the error may be:

```
import numpy as np

width = 512
height = 512
scalar1 = 1
scalar2 = 2

a = np.random.random((height, width, 3))
tmp = np.zeros((height, width))
for i in xrange(width):
    for j in xrange(height):
        tmp[j,i] = np.sqrt((scalar1-a[j,i,1])**2+(scalar2-a[j,i,2])**2)

tmp2 = np.sqrt((scalar1-a[:,:,1])**2+(scalar2-a[:,:,2])**2)

np.allclose(tmp, tmp2)
```

Comment: I assign the temp in the loop to a 2D array later. Changing to np.sqrt gives the same results: the loop is as expected and my vectorized version is not. They are not actually my var names, I'll edit the original question to show a specific test case.